# В заголовок выносится часть кода, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом коде все чисто (как мне кажется;), при этом часть названия статьи почему то выноситься в заголовок

Comment: <h2>Vpn, которые не выйдет оплатить через криптовалюту</h2>

<h3><a id="post-29765-_1vp5mmn5t8sa"></a>Proton</h3>
<img class="wp-image-29787" src="https://gruzdevv.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/word-image-96.jpg" />

Comment: если нужна доп инфа - скажите тут пожалуйста, скину все, что может пригодиться. ибо в вп я ноль

Comment: Комменты не для уточнений. Исправь вопрос. И вообще напиши внятно в чём проблема, что не так.

Comment: Заголовок отражает проблему, я не спец вообще, залил вопрос в надежде, что кто-то сталкивался с этим, поэтому более внятно сформулировать, к сожалению, не могу.

Comment: Ты нечитатель или непониматель? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6688/504949